# Kotlin how to make multiple requests in a queue

Tags: android, kotlin

I have multiple requests, each request return 10 items. Something like this:

```
        var startIndex = 0
        var batchSize = 10
        var totoalCount = 50 
        var requestTimes = totoalCount/batchSize 
        for (index in 1..reqeustTimes) {
           client.request(url, "POST", startIndex) {
               completion(result.map {
                  //store in an array and append the returned items
               })
            startIndex += batchSize
        }
```

But I want to control the order, like put the request in a queue, one finished the start the next one.

How should I do that?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

```
completion: ((Result<JsonObject>) -> Unit)?
```

is an lambda.

**EDIT:**

I can make the request one by one, but the problem right now is the request isn't in order.

```
launch {   
          (1..parameter.totalSize/parameter.batchSize).asFlow()
                    .map { _ -> fetchItem(parameter)}.collect()
}
```

Comment: What is `client` an instance of? is `onSuccess` a function that you pass a callback to?

Comment: Hi, `client` actually is just a common class, the real thing to make the request is  `GDHttpConnector()` from blackberry. I changed `onSuccess` to `Completion` a command lambda, bear with me not quite sure if callback, need to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

You could use coroutine for this purpose,

As an example:

```
// suspend fun main() = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { // for production
fun main() = runBlocking { // for testing (single threaded)
    var startIndex = 0
    val batchSize = 10
    val totoalCount = 50
    var requestTimes = totoalCount / batchSize
    for (index in 1..requestTimes) {
        val result = request(startIndex)
        // do result.onSuccess{} here
        startIndex += batchSize
    }
}

suspend fun request(startIndex: Int) = suspendCoroutine<Result<JsonObject>> {cont ->
    client.fetchItems(startIndex) { cont.resume (it) }
}
```

**NOTE: Since i don't know about what is type of fetchItems{it} in request function, i used `suspendCoroutine<Result<JsonObject>>` change it to what your fetchItems{it} return**

The thread will be suspended till the coroutine is completed and another coroutine could easily occupy that thread till the request has the continuation resumed. So its not like blocking the thread or anything (stupid) :).

**EDIT:** see https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines.experimental/suspend-coroutine.html and https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/where-is-suspendcoroutine-supposed-to-be-used/11190/2

Comment: @William Hu btw do you use coroutine in your current project?

Comment: Hey thanks, I got back after I got solved it. Basically it should be the same idea as yours. I add my own answer too along with the cancel requests functionality. Thanks! let me vote up your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution by **coroutines**.

First, make the `fetchItems` a suspend function:

```
suspend fun fetchItems(paramter: Parameter) {}
```

Then

```
var startIndex = 0
var batchSize = 10
var totoalCount = 50 
var requestTimes = totoalCount/batchSize 


launch {
            (1..requestTimes).asFlow()
                .map {
                    val p = parameter.copy(startIndex = it * 10)
                    fetchItems(p, completion)
                }.collect()
        }
```

Simple enough.

Or you can use another version of launch:

```
         launch {
            repeat(parameter.requestTimes) {
                val p = parameter.copy(startIndex = it * batchSize)
                requestContact(p, completion)
            }
        }
```

**PS**: 1. For the parameter try to use `val` properties to make sure it's thread-safe.

2. Sometimes you may need to cancel the batch requests.

Here is the solution:

```
class Downloader: CoroutineScope by CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default) {

    fun destroy() {
        cancel()
    }

    fun startDownloder() {
        // add above launch in here.
    }
}
```

Then you can:

```
runBlocking  {
            val downloader = Downloader()
            downloader.startDownloder()
            delay(5000L) // this can be used just for debugging to see requests are really canceled
           // Cancel the requests
            downloader.destroy()
        }
```